# Using a sort key from the command line

Tags: python

I need to allow a user defined sort key from the command line, something like

```
sort(key=commandLineArg)
```

However the `commandLineArg` is a string and is not callable. How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you intend for this command line argument to contain? The name of a global function? A class? Arbitrary Python code?

Comment: Please provide examples of what the command-line argument will actually look like.

Comment: The command line argument would be something like str.lower. So the call would be sort(key="str.lower") essentially. This won't work with a string but would work if it was just sort(key=str.lower)

Comment: @JoshBrittain: Please **update** the question with new facts.  Please focus on a command-line argument example. Please don't add comments to a question.  Please make the question as clear and complete as possible.

Comment: All those ()'s aren't really a good idea for a command-line application.  And what -- specific -- format will this mysterious "commandLineArg" take?

Answer (score 3):

You give the example of `str.lower` as a command line parameter. While it is *possible* to convert such a string into a Python object using `eval`, that is risky and I might suggest another step in there. For example:

```
SortKeys = {
    "capitalize": str.capitalize,
    "lower": str.lower,
    "title": str.title,
    "upper": str.upper,
}

if sys.argv[1] in SortKeys:
    sort(..., key=SortKeys[sys.argv[1]])
else:
    print("Unknown sort key:", sys.argv[1])
```

This sort of approach will allow you to better control the possible types of sort key, without allowing arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> sort(key=operator.itemgetter("somekey"))
```

to sort on an attribute of an object, when you only have the attribute name as a string.

Comment: I tried sort(key=operator.itemgetter("str.lower")) and i get a string indices must be integers, not str error

Comment: Can you clarify what strings you're trying to accept as sort keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the given string to get a callable:

```
In [27]: eval('lambda x: x**2')(3)
Out[27]: 9
```

But only do this if you really trust the user!